# Benefits of queue using linkedlist vs queue using array for hash-table bucket?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, hashmap, queue

I know of two ways to implement a queue, using a linked-list or using an array. Which one should I use for making buckets in a hash-table where the hash-table needs to be rehashed when bucket exceeds limit of entries. Is it possible for me to get O(1) en-queue and de-queue along with indexing using some other data-structure?

Using array I can let the bucket size go to higher values, cause indexing in an array lets me use binary search on the keys(inserted in sorted order). Consider the benefits if bucket size becomes 1000, search becomes ln(1000) vs 1000. Insert operation becomes O(n) but, lookup is more common then insert.

Using linked-list I get O(1) insert, delete but also I get O(n).

My question is that, can I get the benefits of both using some other data-structure or is the benefit of using of of these clearly more than the other?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you'd use a queue for a hash table bucket. Why wouldn't you just use a dynamic list?

Comment: @JimMischel Your right, let me explain, editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong question. Rather than worrying about how to handle large numbers of items in a bucket, you should be concerned with why your bucket has become overfull.

Hash tables assume two things:

1. You've selected a hashing function that provides a good distribution of items among buckets.
2. You won't let the load factor get too high. A good hash table implementation will provide pretty decent performance with a load factor up to about 0.8, but beyond that performance drops precipitously. I think most implementations like to keep the load factor under 0.7. So if the number of items in your hash table exceeds 70% of the table's capacity, you should consider increasing the capacity. Most hash table implementations automatically increase the capacity when the load factor goes beyond some threshold.

When you elect to use a hash table, you take on the responsibility of ensuring that both conditions hold true. If you pick a poor hashing function or if you exceed the designed load factor, *performance will suffer*, and no amount of optimizing the bucket structure is going to help you.

The implementation of your bucket's list structure shouldn't matter because your buckets shouldn't be large enough to make a performance difference. A simple linked list gives you O(1) insertion and O(k) lookup (where k is the number of items in the bucket). But k shouldn't be more than 2 or 3, so it doesn't make sense to use an asymptotically more efficient data structure.

Regardless of how you implement the buckets, you're going to pay the price of an O(n) resize from time to time when you exceed the hash table's capacity (or the load factor threshold if your hash table implementation does automatic resizing).

Comment: So I should rehash the table if buckets become too big or if about 70% of it is filled? I should not use another hash table in the bucket.

Comment: @AchyutRastogi: I've never seen an implementation that checks for the number of items in a bucket. Typically what I've seen is a system that, if the current number of items stored exceeds some threshold (usually between 70 and 80 percent of capacity), then the table is rehashed.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the buckets for the hash table, you should use linked lists because they are resizable. The only operation you need to do in buckets within a hash map are to traverse and to append new items, both of which can be accomplished in `O(1)` per element. When you use an array, you allocate memory unnecessarily or too little, as you cannot resize it. Moreover, you shouldn't use a queue, you'd be better off just using an ordinary linked list.